# Is there a way to take low resolution pictures on Android?

Tags: camera

I have a Galaxy S5, and with the native camera app, the smallest possible picture size is a 2.4MB image at 2028x1152 pixels.

However, for the purposes of capturing images for flashcards I use in [Ankidroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ichi2.anki&hl=en), that size is too large. The storage volume adds up quickly and the files are slow to move around the network.

What I really want is to take pictures in the realm of 640x480 pixels or so. I don't need high quality, I need small, quick, and disposable.

**Are there any camera apps, or any other methods, where I can take low resolution images?** My search of Google Play indicates almost all camera apps aspire to take the biggest, sharpest, highest resolution pictures possible.

Comment: I don't know about taking low resolution pictures, but apps like this, reduce resolution for sharing /uploading https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shoozhoo.imageresizer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera) has plenty of options for specifying the resolution.

Look on the settings menu, then Photo settings. You can set it to 640x480 or even 352x288. You can also set the image quality, ie the level of JPEG compression. If you decrease the quality, it will give you smaller file sizes.
[image: Open Camera resolutions]

Comment: Tested it out, and not only does it have more resolution options than the default camera, it's a little faster with slightly sharper pictures as well. Thanks for this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a good alternative. Since your biggest concern is resolution, you can try Photo Studio ([free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kvadgroup.photostudio) or [paid (PRO version)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kvadgroup.photostudio_pro)). It allows you to edit and or export your photos in any resolution possible as desired, you can even alter the aspect ratio of your photos if you like. Through cropping if the phone doesn't put them in the right ratio. This will help you a lot in anything you wanna do. Good luck. It must save you

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That is a viable route to getting a low resolution image, but it does require many steps, and at the rate I'm adding images to my flashcards, the cumulative work adds up. I may utilize this in the meantime, but, I'm going to hold out hope for a more direct camera-to-final-image solution.

Comment: @Questioner welcome always

Answer (score 0):

I think [Resizeme  Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xnview.XnResize) is what you are looking for in terms of *camera to final image to sharing* solution

- It allows you to take photos directly from your device camera
- You can set up the required size you want from the wide range of options or specify the custom size you want
- You can do basic editing functions like cropping etc and save
- On saving, it immediately props up the *direct share* menu to send it to your app or other ways

It's Pro but free for 3 days (that's what prompted me to download and then I recalled your question)

Answer (score 0):

I use an alternative to Google Photos that has the ability to resize photos

There are two galleries which can do that:

- [Simple Gallery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplemobiletools.gallery)
- [QuickPics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder)

In QuickPic the resizing is a bit easier if I recall correctly, currently I am using Simple Gallery.